# e.preventDefault does still loads anchor link in a new tab in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have basically a ajax call that invokes a REST API that gives me list of all names and I have another REST API that matches that. For example,

```
/list gives me: list1,list2,list3
```

and

```
/api/list1.json gives me: json of list1..
```

But I have my code where I loop through all the lists and invoke /api/list1.json

I want that JSON to be displayed in a div when `a` onclick event occurs by grabbing the `href` accordingly without page reload. But right now, since that is also a valid link browser just takes me there.

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
   $.ajax({
     dataType: 'json'
     url: '/lists',
       success: function (data) {


if (data != null) {
                     var html = '<ul>';
                      $.each(data.apis, function (i, item) {
                           //click event
                           $('a').click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
          });


                            html += '<li class="res">';
                            html += '<div class="hed"><h2><a href="/api/' + item + '.json">' + item + '</a></h2></div>';
                            html += '</li>';
                        });

                        html += '</ul>';

                        $('#exDiv').empty();
                        $('#exDiv').append(html);
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error');
                },
                contentType: 'application/json'
            });
         $('a').click(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
          });


        });
```

Apparently I also added `e.preventDefault()` but it still triggers the link to a new tab.

[Link to e.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: show us your click event on a tag

Comment: Where is the preventdefault line? We need more code.

Comment: I added additional code

Comment: Is that it? When is this script executed? If the `a` elements haven't been parsed yet, then jQuery won't pick up anything.

Comment: your ajax function should be inside your click event. so a click event will fire an ajax request.

Comment: try replacing e.preventDefault() with return false;

Comment: As my page loads, this script gets executed as its in the header @MinusFour

Comment: @fscore, then it should be executed when the document is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are dynamically added anchor tags. They don't exist when you add the click event handler to the anchor tags. So when you click these anchors they are going to bypass your jquery event handlers and do what they normally do by default.([further explanation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)) You have the same code again inside the $.each function which might have worked if you had called it after your $('#exDiv').append(html); line. But again they still don't exist when you call it.

Depending on the version of jQuery you're using you should use either "on" or "live". If you are using a version 1.7 or higher use 'on'.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json'
        url: '/lists',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != null) {
                var html = '<ul>';
                $.each(data.apis, function (i, item) {
                    html += '<li class="res">';
                    html += '<div class="hed"><h2><a href="/api/' + item + '.json">' + item + '</a></h2></div>';
                    html += '</li>';
                });
                html += '</ul>';
                $('#exDiv').empty();
                $('#exDiv').append(html);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        },
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });

    $(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

If you're using 1.6 or ealier your click event handler should look like this:

```
$('a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it

Comment: This is sending multiple requests to same href instead of once

Comment: It shouldn't be sending any requests to the href since your event handler is essentially just canceling the click. I'm not sure why you're using anchor tags in the first place if you don't want the click event to do anything. Could you possibly have more than one event handler attached to the anchor?

Comment: is there a way to check the number of event handlers to a anchor tag? and my click on anchor tag basically displays a div below it by calling a function.

Comment: Perhaps, You can sometimes get a clue by using Chromes developer tools. right click on one of the links and click "inspect". then in the top right panel click on the "Event Listeners" tab. Then uncheck the "Framework Listeners" and "Ancestors" checkboxes at the top. Spin open the "click"  and "mousedown" events and see what event listeners are attached. It will tell you if you have an event listener attached but not necessarily where it is or what it does.  jquery event listeners will generally point to your jquery js file. but the listener may be attached anywhere.